# pointing domain to DNS server

Tags: dns, server

I need to point my domain "buafamily.com" to hostinger.co.uk DNS server but i don't know how to.

Please can anyone help?

When i login to my cPanel they notice this:

"Your domain is not pointing to our nameservers at the moment, so services such as FTP, File Manager, E-mail (and others) will not work correctly. You can find our nameservers at the "Accounts -> Details" section. Please mind that DNS might take up to 24 hours to propagate when the change is submitted."

And in account ->details. I found this:

"You can also point your domain ("A" DNS record) to this IP: 31.220.16.179

ns1.hostinger.co.uk 31.170.163.241

ns2.hostinger.co.uk 31.220.23.1

ns3.hostinger.co.uk 173.192.183.247

ns4.hostinger.co.uk 31.170.164.249"

I did all i can to understand but failed. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like buafamily.com is registered with Vitalwerks/NO-IP.COM.  You should have information from when you signed up with them.

You'll want to contact Vitalwerks (or log into their domain management system) and change the nameservers to be the ns1-4.hostinger.co.uk servers instead.